# Cliques in Cayley graph on $n$-cycles

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, permutations, cayley-graphs

Let $S\subset S_n$ be the set of all $n$-cycles. I want to know if the Cayley graph $(S_n,S)$ has large dense subgraphs. I'm expecting it to not have super-polynomial size and $1-o(1)$ dense subgraphs.

However, one good starting point maybe the following question:

> What is the size of the largest clique (and biclique) of $(S_n,S)$?

As $(S_n,S)$ is a subgraph of the Birkhoff polytope graph $B_n$, a bound on the clique size of $B_n$ might be also helpful. I find [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/282496/clique-and-chromatic-number-of-cycle-graph-of-permutations) closely related, but no bounds in terms of $n$ were given there.

Another related result I find is on the independence number of $B_n$, proved in [Kane, Lovett and Rao](http://ieee-focs.org/FOCS-2017-Papers/3464a252.pdf):

> The independence number $\alpha(B_n)$ satisfies $n!/4^n\leq\alpha(B_n)\leq n!/2^{(n-4)/2}$.

Comment: If $n$ is prime, then tge powers of one cycle form a largest size clique. Ondeed, among $n+1$ permutations, two send $1$ to the same element, hence they dp not differ by an $n$-cycle.

Comment: This argument shows also that a subgraph on $\Omega(n)$ vertices cannot have edge density $1-o(1)$.

Comment: On the other hand, if $n$ is even, then any $n$-cycle is odd, hence the graph is bipartite, and there is no triangle in it.

Answer (score 3):

Ilya correctly wrote in the comments that a clique cannot be larger than $n$, and also that size $n$ is not possible when $n$ is even (except $n=2$).

Cliques of size exactly $n$ are studied under the name of *pan-Hamiltonian latin squares*. It is an unsolved problem for which $n$ they exist. In  [this paper](http://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v6i1r9) Ian Wanless conjectures that they exist for all odd $n$, and notes that the conjecture has been proved by construction up to $n=49$. I don't know if that value has been increased since then.

Comment: Thank you. Are there results on bicliques known?

Comment: @WillardZhan Not that I know of, but I'm not a specialist in this subject. Ian's email is easy to locate, you should ask him.